# Has Russia, as of August 21st, violated any gas contracts with Germany?

Tags: russian-federation, germany, gas

With the looming winter, the question of Russia [delivering](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/europa/tschechien-oesterreich-gaslieferungen-101.html) [sufficient](https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/verbraucher/fuellstaende-gasspeicher-bundesnetzagentur-ukraine-krieg-russland-nord-stream-gaspreise-101.html) [gas](https://www.tagesschau.de/notfallplan-gasversorgung-nordstream-gasembargo-lng-gaspreise-101.html) for power, warmth, and industry is frequently discussed across German media. However, as far as I am aware, only the possible threat of Russia delivering insufficient or no gas at all has been discussed so far. Also, only the phrasing 'delivery of X% of the technically possible amount'  is used which does not state what the actually ordered amount was. I keep wondering: **Has Russia, as of August 21st, actually reduced the amount of delivered gas below their contractual obligations in violation of their contract?**

As far as I know the only reduction(s) of gas delivery were announced and [officially due to required repairs](https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/konjunktur/nord-stream-gas-reduzierung-101.html) and ([probably?](https://www.merkur.de/wirtschaft/sanktionen-gas-krise-scholz-turbine-nord-stream-1-russland-deutschland-ukraine-krieg-zr-91703163.html)) within contractual limitations.

*I would be satisfied with news, or official statements that are detailing information on how much gas has actually been ordered in comparison to how much gas has been delivered? However, a more in-depth perspective on gas contracts, e.g., how long can a reparation be contractually justified, would be much appreciated.*

The only hint I found of contractual violations is in the [context of Uniper](https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/uniper-milliardenverlust-gaslieferungen-energieversorger-101.html) insolvency. However, the phrasing and article seems to avoid to actually call out any contractual violations.

> A bit more than half [of the expected losses], are in connection with
> expected future consequences of limits of gas imports from Russia.
>
> Etwas mehr als die Hälfte davon, 6,5 Milliarden Euro, stünden im
> Zusammenhang mit erwarteten künftigen Auswirkungen von
> Gaslieferbeschränkungen aus Russland, teilte der Konzern heute mit.

Comment: Probably impossible to answer since the contracts are typically not public.  Scholz complained that Russia isn't taking back a turbine after it was fixed, and so they reduced the flow claiming technical problems. Whether that's a violation of contract depends on the fine print, which isn't public, AFAIK,  and even if it were, it would probably be a matter for courts to decide. The famous picture with Scholz standing in front of the turbine https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/8/3/germanys-scholz-blames-russia-in-energy-row-says-tribune-works

Comment: @Fizz Yes, that part is *might* not be answerable. However, the question whether Russia reduced the delivered amount below the ordered amount should be, it would be quite sad from a journalistic perspective if nobody actually asked that question and it is quite possible that the currently delivered amount suffices to fulfill a minimal obligation?

Comment: @Fizz the information for a positive response to the question concerning other european countries [does exist and is quoted in German public media](https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/gas-lieferstopp-russland-niederlande-103.html). "Beim nun verhängten Lieferstopp geht es um Liefermengen von zwei Milliarden Kubikmeter Gas, die vom 31. Mai bis zum 30. September bestellt waren." -> "The delivery stop affects two billion m^3 ordered gas between the 31. of Mai until the 30th of September".

Comment: Wasn't the switch from €/$ payments to Russian rubles be a breach of contract? When that was in the news the media clearly stated that switching to rubles would be a breach of contract but I don't recall whether the switch was just threatened or actually carried through.

Comment: @quarague The switch was kind of carried out in a very roundabout way, where each side could still argue that either nothing changed or everything changed. I.e. the customers still pay in non-rubles but the conversion takes place in Russia and Russia gets the money in rubles. You really need to be a lawyer (or team of lawyers being experts in these fields) to get a feeling if this is or isn't a breach of contract. It may well be.

Comment: I have no idea whether such a thing has actually happened, but it's conceivable that Russia could falsely claim the existence of circumstances that allow it to reduce deliveries according to the contract.  This is normally known as fraud.  The question allows for the possibility of fraud by saying that some reductions were "officially due [to] required repairs," implying that they might not actually have been caused by repairs.  But the question seems to accept that this isn't a breach of contract.  Should we infer that disingenuousness and fraud are beyond the scope of the question?

Comment: @phoog yes, for the sake of keeping this question fact based and political alignment free I would prefer a fact based answer using official numbers and not solely interpreting current official statements and maneuvering. However, discussing the caveat of fraudulent behavior as part of the answer would be appreciated and in my opinion somewhat required to keep the desired neutrality. However, numbers first, interpretation second.

Comment: "numbers first, interpretation second" Then probably we can only say that so far there is no officially recognized breach of contract, whatever that means in reality. The problem is that even numbers are that unambiguous.

Comment: @phoog And guess what, they found an oil leak in the remaining turbine, so NS1 is off for good https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-62766867

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All I can really [tell you](https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/russias-gazprom-declares-force-majeure-gas-supplies-europe-2022-07-18/) is  that back in mid July Gazprom declared *force majeure* on NS1 but that one its (main) German receivers rejected the claim, while the other refused to comment on the legal angle:

> Russia's Gazprom has told customers in Europe it cannot guarantee gas supplies because of "extraordinary" circumstances, according to a letter seen by Reuters, upping the ante in an economic tit-for-tat with the West over Moscow's invasion of Ukraine.
>
> The Russian state gas monopoly said in a letter dated July 14 that it was retroactively declaring force majeure on supplies from June 14. [...]
>
> A trading source, asking not to be identified because of the sensitivity of the issue, said the force majeure concerned supplies through Nord Stream 1.
>
> "This sounds like a first hint that the gas supplies via NS1 will possibly not resume after the 10-day maintenance has ended," said Hans van Cleef, senior energy economist at ABN Amro.
>
> “Depending on what ‘extraordinary’ circumstances have in mind in order to declare the force majeure, and whether these issues are technical or more political, it could mean the next step in escalation between Russia and Europe/Germany," he added.
>
> Uniper, Germany's biggest importer of Russian gas, was among the customers that said it had received a letter, and that it had formally rejected the claim as unjustified.
>
> RWE (RWEG.DE), Germany's largest power producer and another importer of Russian gas, also said it has received a force majeure notice.
>
> "Please understand that we cannot comment on its details or our legal opinion," the company said.

What that means, [in general](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/force_majeure):

> Force majeure is a provision in a contract that frees both parties from obligation if an extraordinary event directly prevents one or both parties from performing.

FWTW, apparently, the politico-technical response from Moscow [was](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/8/3/germanys-scholz-blames-russia-in-energy-row-says-tribune-works) the suggestion to open NS2, which they also said it was a German inquiry (made by former chancellor Schröder):

> “Putin explained everything in detail, and the former chancellor asked if it was possible to use Nord Stream 2 in a critical situation,” Peskov said. “Putin was not the initiator, Putin did not offer to turn it on, but Putin said that it is technologically possible and this complex mechanism is ready for instant use.”

On the same day, Gazprom themselves [said](https://twitter.com/Reuters/status/1554922643685621762) that getting/accepting  back the NS1 turbine (the one that Scholz is photographed standing in front of) is impossible due to sanctions despite Scholz' claim to the contrary. I was only able to [find](https://mailbd.net/news/gazprom-explained-why-it-does-not-take-a-turbine-for-nord-stream-from-germany-3301/) a horrible (probably machine) translation of the full
statement by Gazprom. Apparently they seem to be saying that shipping the turbine not directly from Canada to Russia was bad (breach of contract, maybe?) and likewise not
shipping it on time, so they are asking for some kind of guarantees they won't be affected by sanctions (again?). Found a better translation [here](https://www.spglobal.com/commodityinsights/en/market-insights/latest-news/natural-gas/080422-russias-gazprom-says-other-nord-stream-gas-turbines-also-face-sanctions-block). They seem to be saying that they're afraid of being held legally liable for breaching sanctions in Canada or in the UK if they take delivery from Germany, due to the complicated nature of the maintenance contract.

Comment: Btw. just in case somebody wanted to find out if that was or wasn't a breach of contract (not that it really matters much currently with a war going on), which jurisdiction would one need to go to? Is this known? Some WTO arbitration court maybe?

Comment: FTWT, a subsequent 3-week "trolling" by Siemens on Twitter [didn't](https://www.opindia.com/2022/08/russia-gazprom-trolls-siemens-energy-turbine-energy-conflict-nordstream-1-supplies-to-europe/) impress Gazprom one bit, to change their mind regarding the turbine. (Gazprom responded in kind on Twitter.)

Comment: @Trilarion: typically there are arbitration clauses in the contract(s). Without seeing them, it's impossible to tell where. https://www.reuters.com/article/gazprom-overgas-court-idAFL5N17A467

Comment: @Fizz From the article: "Siemens: let's make a playlist to accompany a genocide campaign we are heavily investing into with our money. It's been to long since the last one we payed for" Interesting take

Comment: What do you mean when you say "politico-technical response from Moscow" in comparison to just a "response from Moscow"?

Comment: The last quote is misleading without the rest of the article. The person described as "former chancellor" is former chancellor Gerhard Schröder who has a position in the Nord Stream 2 consortium, and not the current chancellor, Olaf Scholz you go on writing about. That makes the whole commotion about NS2 a lot less authoritative.

Comment: @antipattern: good point (updated).