# Contract breaches during war and arbitrations afterwards

Tags: world-war-ii, contract-law

My question is inspired by [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74930/has-russia-as-of-today-violated-any-gas-contracts-with-germany).

Large corporations or even states are signing contracts during peace periods. However, it happens that wars can be declared (sic...). This is the case of the Ukraine / Russia war and the impact on Gazprom contracts.

My questions are the following:

- Do we have significant examples of major breaches of contracts between states (or large corporations of states) in history induced by wars, especially during WWII?
- What were the arbitration attempts to resolve the issues?
- Is there examples of successful negotiations (arbitrations, litigations...) that happened after the close of the wars?

Comment: Do you know the concept of 'force majeure'. The idea is that one side can get out of a contract without penalties if some major event outside of the power of the parties to the contract makes fulfilling the contract impossible or unreasonable. A war usually counts as 'force majeure'.

Comment: @quarague "A war usually counts as 'force majeure'." But only if a court decides that it counts. It may be that there aren't many such definitive decisions.

Comment: Do you also count treaties between countries as contracts or are you only interested in contracts between private, commercial entities?

Comment: Removed a note "Note: I'm new to Politics stackexhange and I have to admit that my question may be much too broad... Let me know if that is the case!" by asker from the question and re-post it here as a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm mainly interested in contracts that are commercial by nature.

Comment: I suggest migrating to https://history.stackexchange.com/ Generally speaking asking how commercial issues were dealt way back then is OT here. Even comparison with the Vietnam era have been deemed so.

Comment: Any reason for focusing on arbitration rather than litigation?

Comment: @ohwilleke I used arbitration as a wording for *resolving the conflict* in a broad sense. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score -1):

When the Nazi Germany attacked the Soviet Union, their government has ordered that all payments for goods which were already shipped from SU to be sent to a special account of German bank. Apparently they expected to take over SU and then use those money for the functioning of their new, dependent government of Russia. It did not exactly pan out but the approach seems sound.